# ¿Eventos de interfaz gráfica en otra clase?

Tags: java

Tengo una interfaz que defino mediante el constructor, contiene un JFrame que a su vez tiene un JPanel en donde agrego un JTextField y un JButton. Mi idea es capturar los eventos del JTextField y JButton en otra clase para usarlos.

Mi problema es que no hallo la manera de capturar el evento, inicio la interfaz y acciono el botón pero no ocurre nada, he instanciado pero no logro capturar el evento.

¿Qué me recomiendan hacer?,¿qué estoy pasando por alto?

Gracias.

Código

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame{

public JTextField text;
public JButton btnIniciar;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Ventana ventana = new Ventana();
    ventana.setVisible(true);

}

public Ventana(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(450, 300, 470, 226);
    setTitle("Prueba");

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(); 
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    text= new JTextField();
    text.setBounds(143, 80, 150, 25);
    contentPane.add(text);

    btnIniciar = new JButton("Enviar");
    btnIniciar.setFont(new Font("Microsoft YaHei Light", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnIniciar.setBounds(321, 149, 105, 27);

    contentPane.add(btnIniciar);
    btnIniciar.addActionListener(new Evento());
}
```

-

```
public class Evento implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    Ventana ventana = new Ventana();
    if (ventana.btnIniciar == evento.getSource()) {
        System.out.println(ventana.text.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostar un [mcve] de tu código?

Comment: Hay lo adjunté.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    Ventana ventana = new Ventana();
    if (ventana.btnIniciar == evento.getSource()) {
        System.out.println(ventana.text.getText());
```

Este código lo que hace es **crear una nueva instancia de `Ventana` e imprimir el valor de su campo `text`**. Pero el problema es que:

1. El botón de esa `Ventana` no es el que lanza el evento, así que `ventana.btnIniciar == evento.getSource()` devuelve `false`.
2. En esa instancia de Ventana tú no has puesto ningún valor, porque no es la que se muestra por pantalla. Es un objeto completamente independiente. Así que lo que haría sería imprimir una cadena vacía<sup>1</sup>.

Lo que tienes que hacer es pasar a `Evento` una referencia a la instancia de `Ventana` que se está mostrando; por ejemplo mediante un constructor:

```
public class Evento ... {
   private Ventana ventana;

   public Evento(Ventana ventana) {
     this.ventana = ventana;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
     if (this.ventana.btnIniciar == evento.getSource()) {
        System.out.println(this.ventana.text.getText());
     }
   }
}
```

y, al crear la instancia de Evento, pasar la referencia<sup>2</sup>.

```
btnIniciar.addActionListener(new Evento(this));
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Truco: A la hora de imprimir un mensaje para verificarlo, añade algún texto fijo. Así sabrás si el problema es que no se hace nada o si el programa funciona pero imprime la cadena vacía o espacios en blanco o similar. Por ejemplo: `System.out.println("Es campo texto es: " + ventana.text.getText());`.

<sup>2</sup>Siendo puntillosos, esto no se tendría que hacer desde el constructor de `Ventana` por un problema que se llama *instance leaking*; sería mejor hacer un método (por ejemplo `inicializar`) para incluir esta lógica.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y el apunte.